What is the language generated by the context free grammar $S \rightarrow aSb \ | \ bSa| \ \epsilon $
I can't identify the language generated by the following grammar, $$S \rightarrow  aSb \ | \ bSa| \ \epsilon $$
Based on my understating of CFGs, the language generated would be $L(G) = (L_1 + L_2 + L_3)^*$, where  $$\begin{align} L_1 = (ab + ba)^* \\ L_2 = \{a^nb^n | n \geq 0 \} \\ L_3 = \{b^na^n | n \geq 0 \} \end{align}$$
And, $L(G) \neq \{ w \  | \ w \ \epsilon \ (a+b)^* , n_a(w) = n_b(w)\}$.
What is the actual language generated by the grammar ? And is that language a CFL ?

Exercise: what is the language generated by $S\to aSbS\mid bSaS\mid \varepsilon$?

@Nathaniel, the grammar $S \to aSbS \mid bSaS\mid \varepsilon$ is equivalent to $S \to SS \mid aSb \mid bSa \mid \varepsilon $, so $ L = { w   \mid  w  \varepsilon \ (a+b)^* , n_a(w) = n_b(w)}$

That's it! (If I interpret $\varepsilon$ in the definition of $L$ as a $\in$)

Since each production introduces one letter to the left and one letter to the right of $S$, we see that $S$ keeps sitting in the middle of the word. The two subwords left and right of $S$ are “doubly mirror images” of each other: they are reversed (as each production adds one letter to the end of the left subword and to the beginning of the right subword), and $a$ is exchanged with $b$ (since each production adds $a$ to the left subword and $b$ to the right subword, or vice versa). Thus,
$$L(G)=\bigl\{w\overline w^R:w\in\{a,b\}^*\bigr\}=\bigl\{w\in\{a,b\}^*:w^R=\overline w\bigr\},$$
where $w^R$ is the usual reversal operator, and $\overline w$ is the operator that changes each occurrence of $a$ in $w$ to $b$, and vice versa. You can prove this formally by induction on the length of the derivation.

It can be tricky to go from formal specification to informal specification.
In a rigorous sense, the best description of the language is the grammar you have already provided.
But we can try to characterize it, starting from a few observations:

we have the empty word and all other rules of production add two symbols, so all words in the language will have an even length
each production rules adds both an $a$ and a $b$, so we will have words with equal number of $a$s and $b$s
these words have the property that they (and each of their "inner" strings obtained by removing the first and last characters) start and end with a different symbol.

Perhaps there is a briefer way to express this in plain English and I'm just missing it at the moment.
I'm not sure how you got the union of those three languages, but we can see at $L_1$ is erroneous, as it contains the word $abba$ which cannot be part of our language.
As for the last question, there is such a things as a "context-free grammar": where each rule has a left-hand-side consisting of a single non-terminal and a right-hand-side consisting of a (possible empty) string of terminals and non-terminals.
Any language generated by a context-free grammar is a context-free language; since your grammar has this property, you can be sure that its language is context-free as well.
But assuming, you also meant to ask whether the language is irregular, it is indeed so; you can verify this, for example, by using the pumping lemma for regular languages:

select a word such as $a^pb^p$
the pumped component can be formed only of $a$s
pumping it once yields a word with at least one more $a$ than $b$s; so not part of our language,

